# Greenhills multi software Icon is not shown in Window 10's Toolbar / Alt+Tab

Tags: greenhills

Greenhills multi software is installed in windows 10 PC. After launching the software i could see the GUI of IDE but once i minimized i couldn't find the software icon to anywhere in Toolbar or Alt+Tab except task manager.

I have searched all the option provided in software but couldn't find the solution.

Provide the option to enable feature to show GHS multi icon on toolbar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things:

1. showing multi in taskbar - press Win key -> type "Multitasking settings" -> select "All desktops" under Virtual desktops settings (this didn't solve the problem with Alt+Tab; so
2. Change registry - https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/